# Why is my iMac awaken itself every now and then - Even if I've not even close to it? Same thing with my Macbook pro

Tags: macbook-pro, imac, sleep-wake

So for example, I'm about to sleep and laying in my bed, and suddenly my iMac screen turns on and shows the login screen - I'm not close it and have not touched the mouse or anything that should have to awaken the mac. Pretty annoying since it does light up my whole room.

It doesn't happen every night but sometimes it does - Maybe once a week or something - and now it happens with my Macbook as well..

Anyone have an answer on this?

Comment: Have you got « wake on network activity » set? So it wakes for an email etc...

Comment: Is it the setting in "Power save"? I thought that setting was only for enabling/disabling internet access during sleep. I've tried to turn it off now.